How to find sum of items in a decimal list using superset's handle bars chart
I have Apache Superset handlebar chart in which I wish to show sum of data in list instead of each items in list
HandleBar templete
<div class="data-list">
  {{#each data}}
    <h4>{{value}}</h4>
  {{/each}}
  <h6> Value </h6>
</div>

value list = {123.45,65.78,8.45}
Expected Result :
197.68
Value

I tried using a script tag within template its not working
    <ul class="data-list">
    {{#each data}}
    <h4>{{value}}</h4>
    {{/each}}
    <h4>Total Value: {{sumValue data}}</h4>
    </ul>
    <script>
      Handlebars.registerHelper('sumValue', function(data) {
      let sum = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      sum += parseFloat(data[i].Value);
      }
       return sum.toFixed(2); // Optionally, you can round the sum to 2 decimal places
      });
    </script>


as this is a superset chart I don't think script will work is there any helper function that can help me achieve this
